# Linear Algebra: How to interpret vectors and equations of a system of equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, coordinate-systems

From Strang's 18.06 Linear Algebra OCW Course I realized that there is a row view and column view to interpret a matrix and the solution to Ax = b. Well the view made sense but it was hard understanding the matrix operations from this. So I checked out other lectures on Youtube and found this https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab which explained matrices as Linear Transformations which eased me on the geometric part.

But as I stared to wonder the relationship between the system of equations and the columns of Matrix A in Ax = b. I couldn't find any connection!
Suppose I have this system of equations:

x + 2y = 4

x + 3y = 5

Solution is x = 2 and y = 1 which is essentially the point of intersection of line x = 4 - 2y and x = 5 - 3y.

Now if I go to solve this equation in vector form. I have the matrix A = \begin{bmatrix}1&2\\1&3\end{bmatrix} 
Now I have 2 vectors [1 1] and [2 3] which are the basis for my newly transformed space and I have to find the vector in my original vector space that gives me b = [4 5].
Or by Strang's way I have to find such a linear combination of column vectors of A that gives me b.

So my question is not why but HOW this equations of line is converted into vector and how can we say that they are equivalent? I can't seem to find an explanation of the relationship between the coordinate space and vector space. How does the coefficients of the x and y variable of the equations transform into i and j basis for the vector space?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I entirely get your question right but in essence
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2\\1 & 3\end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}4 \\ 5\end{bmatrix}$$
is the same as splitting $A$ into its columns via
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}\cdot x + \begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 3\end{bmatrix}\cdot y= \begin{bmatrix}4 \\ 5\end{bmatrix}$$
which is the same as 
$$\begin{bmatrix}x \\ x\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}2y \\ 3y\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}4 \\ 5\end{bmatrix}$$
which gives you
$$\begin{bmatrix}x+2y=4 \\ x+3y=5\end{bmatrix} $$
which is the description in coordinte space you were referring to. Is it any of these steps that you are struggling with or did I misunderstand your question?

*edit*: Geometrically, the two interpretations live in different spaces. The second equation lives in the column space of the matrix and asks: how much do I need to go in direction of the first column and second column to reach the vector on the RHS? How can I express the RHS as a linear combination of the two columns?

Here is a picture (solid lines: first and second column vector (up to first dot); dashed lines: space spanned by each column, red cross: target (RHS), reachable by one green and two blue or two blue and one green):

[image: Interpretation 1: column space]

The second interpretation lives in the row space of the matrix and says: each row of the matrix is one line (in general hyperplane) of possible solutions. If I intersect all the lines (hyperplanes) I get the one solution that satisfies all equations simultaneously.

Here is a picture (notice that here the axis are x and y, not so in interpretation one, where x and y are the "lengths" of the vectors, i.e., how far you go along each):

[image: Interpretation 2: row space]

Geometrically, these two are separate, as they are in different spaces and therefore we cannot directly connect them. Just imagine the matrix would not be square but, say, 3x2. Then columnspace vectors would live in $\mathbb{R}^3$ whereas rowspace vectors would live in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: I was referring to the relationship between the solution obtained directly from the equation (which gives me the intersection point by substitution) and the solution obtained from the matrix (using Gaussian elimination). How are they equal geometrically? How can be interpret them?

Comment: Okay sorry for misunderstanding your initial question. I have made some edits to my response. Does this help?

Comment: Yeah you are right but shouldn't be probably looking at rowspace as the span of row 1 and row 2 vectors? And (correct me if I am wrong) the vector interpretation is hypothetical for ease of understanding of Linear system of equations.

Comment: The row space of your matrix is the space spanned by your row 1 and row 2 vectors $\mathbf{r}_1=[1,2]$ and $\mathbf{r}_1=[1,3]$ which since they are linearly independent span the whole $\mathbb{R}^2$. However, $\mathbf{z}=[x, y]$ lives also in the row space so its role is not to give linear combinations of your rows (which you would only get by multiplying A from the left). Instead, given $\mathbf{r}_1$ and $\mathbf{r}_2$ we seek for $\mathbf{z}$ such that $<\mathbf{r}_1,\mathbf{z}>=4$ and $<\mathbf{r}_1,\mathbf{z}>=5$.

Comment: which are essentially the equations we were searching for. But since as you have mentioned above in your answer above, the two spaces are not directly connected so what's the role rowspace plays in this? I mean we can do good without other three fundamental subspaces?

Comment: For really understanding linear systems of equations, all four subspaces are useful. Maybe you don't need it for a 2x2 matrix. But consider a 5x4 matrix of rank two. Its row space is a 2-D subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$, its column space a 2-D subspace of $\mathbb{R}^5$. The matrix maps vectors from row to column space. Its pseudo-inverse maps from column space back to row space. Add any element outside the row space gives you a valid solution (the one in the row space has min.norm). Any vector outside the col. space is not representable (the projection on it gives you the least squares solution).

Comment: Thank you so much Florian. I'm glad you've helped me out on this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49990/discussion-between-user5482992-and-florian).