# Basic Linear Algebra Visualisation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

I am a novice working my way through Gilbert Strang's Introduction to Linear Algebra.

I am confused about linear combinations and how they work geometrically.

In the book, three vectors are defined:

w1=$\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
2\\ 
3
\end{bmatrix} $
w2 = $\begin{bmatrix}
4\\ 
5\\ 
6
\end{bmatrix}$ 
w3 = $\begin{bmatrix}
7\\ 
8\\ 
9
\end{bmatrix} $

They are then rewritten as a matrix

$\begin{bmatrix}
1 &  4& 7\\ 
2 &  5& 8\\ 
3 &  6& 9
\end{bmatrix}$
$\begin{bmatrix}
a1\\ 
a2\\
a3 
\end{bmatrix}$

I can plot the vectors w1, w2 and w3, individually on the x, y and z axis.

Now, in matrix form, the w1 vector represents the first column and in the x1, x2 and x3 positions in the basic x,y,z 3x3 matrix  (row one  = (x1, y1, z1)).

Can the rows of the matrix be meaningfully plotted on the x, y, z axis?

I think I am probably missing something very basic, but it does not feel right to take the column vectors, and then in a matrix, multiplying through the rows.

My second question is related.  The three vectors lie on a plane as $w_2 = (w_1 + w_3)/2$.  Strang comments "According to linear algebra, the rows must also lie on a plane".  Can someone explain the reasoning behind this, again the connection between matrix rows and columns.

Comment: If the columns of $A$ are the column vectors $a_1, a_2, a_3$ (so in other words $A = \begin{bmatrix} a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \end{bmatrix}$), it's often useful to think of $Ax$ as being *a linear combination of the columns of $A$*.  That is, $Ax = x_1 a_1 + x_2 a_2 + x_3 a_3.$  That is my favorite way to think about matrix-vector multiplication.

Comment: Strang's writing style is very friendly, but also sometimes confusing, as he'll make remarks like that without any justification — but the justification will come several chapters later. But, yes, make sure you completely understand the two ways of thinking of matrix times vector: (1) You take linear combinations of the columns according to the entries of the vector; (2) you take the vector of *dot products* of the row vectors with the vector.

Comment: Similar questions have been answered well in different ways in the following questions:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2348233/reconciling-the-column-and-the-row-pictures-for-matrices     and    https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2055226/linear-algebra-how-to-interpret-vectors-and-equations-of-a-system-of-equations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*First question:*

They of course can be plotted , but not in a ‘natural’ way. Your difficulties, I think, come from the fact that a $3\times3$ matrix has two interpretations:

On the one hand, it can be seen as the concatenation of the columns corresponding to the coordinates of three vectors. This interpretation is used in the so-called *‘change of basis matrix’*.

On the other hand, it can be seen as the coefficients of a linear map  from $\mathbf R^3$ to $\mathbf R^3$. As such, for technical reasons, to obtain the coordinates of the image of a vector $\;\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}$, you have to multiply each *row* of the matrix by the *column vector*.

*Second question:*

In this matrix, the rank of the system of vectors is $2$, i.e. they generate a subspace of dimension $2$. A theorem asserts that in a square matrix, the row rank is equal to the column rank. Hence there exists also a linear relation between the rows.

Comment: That's great Bernard, thank you very much.  When we multiply the rows of the matrix with the image vector x,y,z, we appear to be multiplying the x component of the three column vectors (w1, w2, w3), across the three dimensions (treating it as if it is in x,y,z).  Is this part of the R3 -> R3 transformation?  If so, do you have any literature on this?  Thanks again, this has been bothering me for some time.

Comment: This link to[mathinsight.org](http://mathinsight.org/matrices_linear_transformations) explain things in a short and simple way, for me.